# Sentry Java 5.7.4 Client/Browser tags not shown

Tags: java, logging, sentry

So please tell me if I'm just missing something here, but here is the issue.

- Sentry Java updated from legacy 1.7.3 -> 5.7.4
- Update working showing - release, username, stack trace, extras all showing
- tags like browser, browser.name, client_os, client_os.name, url not being captured
- runtime and runtime.name are captured now (not captured in our implementation of 1.7.3)

We need the browser/os tags to be captured. I was under the impression that these were captured via the init? Maybe I'm wrong here. Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 1.7 servlet integration was baked into the Sentry Code. Starting from 3.x there is a [separate module for servlet integration](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/java/guides/servlet/). If you use Spring or Spring Boot, you should look into [dedicated modules](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/java/guides/spring-boot/) for these.